# Как очистить кэш на стороне клиента?

Tags: wordpress, кэширование

Здравствуйте! Расскажите, пожалуйста, как принудительно очистить или обновить кэш своего сайта на стороне клиента, для того чтобы у него заработали новые стили CSS?
Мой сайт на Wordpress, но строки `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />`в header.php нет, наверное стили подключены как-то по другому.

Comment: Сейчас еще раз проверил, - такой строки кода ни в header.php, ни в других файлах темы, к сожалению, нет.. Возможно есть какой-то еще способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Современные темы подключают стили через хук `wp_enqueue_style()` в файле functions.php. В стандартной теме twentyseventeen выглядит это так:

```
function twentyseventeen_scripts() {
    // прочий код...
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    // прочий код...
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyseventeen_scripts' );
```

Функция `get_stylesheet_uri()` возвращает полный url файла style.css. Примерно такой: `http://mysite.org/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css`.

Если вы не создавали дочернюю тему (а судя по вопросу - не создавали), то строку вида

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

в примере выше надо заменить на

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css?ver=xxx' );
```

где xxx - произвольно выбранный номер версии файла style.css.

Ну, а вообще-то, правки темы надо выносить в дочернюю тему (иначе все слетит при обновлении темы). Инструкция на русском по созданию дочерних тем [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

Comment: Спасибо! Я читал, что шрифты можно добавлять через этот хук, не знал, что и общий файл стилей тоже. Подскажите, пожалуйста, то есть при обновлении темы (если нет дочерней) все изменения style.css, все анимации, шрифты, добавленные через @font-face - все слетит?

Comment: Слетит теоретически вообще все, целиком. Что-то может и остаться, зависит от состава обновления. Насколько я знаю, обновления самого WP устроены так, что обновляются только те файлы, что изменились при переходе к новой версии. А вот темы и плагины перезаписываются полностью.

Comment: Благодарю. Это очень полезно, действительно.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

1. Открываем для редактирования файл «header.php».
2. Находим код .
   Добавляем в нем после style.css следующее значение «?qqq», а после screen через запятую прописываем projection. Код будет выглядеть так:

   **qqq** можно заменить на любые другие цифры, это не имеет значения. Главное, каждый раз, когда вы вносите изменения в ваш файл style.css, изменяйте это число на новое.

Answer (score -1):

Для обновления css файла, необходимо добавить версию

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css?v=2" type="text/css" />
```

Обычно стили подключаются в header.php. Пройдитесь поиском по файлам шаблона и найдите где могут подключаться данные стили.